# control windows services in C, C++

Tags: c++, c, service

I need to monitor the status and also controlling the status of the services in windows with C or C++ programming. I have done it in C# .... but I need help how to do it in C or C++ ??

Comment: And what kind of help do you need exactly? What is your question?

Comment: question is - how can i change current state of a windows service from a C/C++ program ?? [ for xample say, Mysql is running as a service ... how can i change its status from a c/c++ program ?? ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following list of WINAPI functions will be useful:

- [OpenSCManager()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684323%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [OpenService()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684330%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [ControlService()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682108%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [CloseServiceHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682028%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

There are many other service related functions which are listed on each of these pages.

Comment: thanks ... but is there any example code or link available ??? If any plz be requested to post.